# Why a upcase function made my rspec test to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm developing a sign in/out function on a web app that i'm building for learning.

During the week, i wasn't able to pass the following rspec test:

```
    describe "sucessfull log in" do
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

    before do
        visit signin_path
        fill_in "Email", with: user.email.upcase
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button 'Sign in'
    end

    it {should have_title(user.name)}
    it {should have_link('Account')}
    it {should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user))}
    it {should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path)}
end
```

Then yesterday and end up re writing this code again, but forgot to add that `.upcase` function. I Left just `.upcase.email`. Suddenly, the test passed.

Ok, i'm a newbie developer... so what happaned? Why the upcase function did not let rspec log in successfully?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it just RSpec? Maybe the test just fails because you cannot log in with an uppercase email.

Comment: Could you add your UserController and your User model, so we can compare validations you make and why it causes your test to fail

Comment: Does your User model also force email to upcase before storing the record?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you upcasing the email?  Would you be equally surprised if `.reverse` made it fail?  You're changing the email address.

`EXAMPLE@EMAIL.COM` is not the same as `example@email.com`, strictly speaking.  It might be equivalent for your application, but you need to make the application know that.

Are you using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)?  If so, the `config/devise.rb` file will have:

```
# Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
# These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
# to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
```

Which should make what you're doing work.  If you're not using it, whatever framework you're using will probably have a similar option, and if you're doing it yourself, you'll need to handle it yourself.

Comment: Presumably the email is being upcased because it is used for authentication.  Exactly as devise can do as you show in your example.  Whilst the non-domain part of an email address can be case-sensitive it would be unusual to allow this if it were being used for user authentication.

Comment: (Sorry, I didn't mean to down-vote the answer - clicked there by accident and now it's locked on me so I can't remove it.)